# How do I avoid creating folders as root when running a python script under sudo?

Tags: python, unix, root

The question title pretty sums it up. I'm running a Python script which has the `os.mkdir()` function in it under sudo (because other functions need it). When I run it with `sudo`, the folder created has `root` as the owner and the only one with access rights. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use `os.chown()` and `os.chmod()`?

Comment: I tried it (with `os.chmod(filedir, stat.S_IWOTH)`) and is not working. Permissions still being rwxr-xr-x. `os.chown()` is not a portable solution I think.

Comment: Why do you consider `os.chmod()` to be portable and `os.chown()` not to be?  Does it work correctly if you replace `filedir` with a string literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create directories with the [install](http://man.cx/?page=install&do%5Bgo%5D=go) command, which changes ownership and permissions automatically.

```
install -o myuser -d -o 0755 /tmp/mydir
```

Answer (score 2):

When sudo is run, the environment variables `SUDO_UID` and `SUDO_GID` are set to the uid and gid of the user running sudo. So:

```
uid = os.environ.get("SUDO_UID")
gid = os.environ.get("SUDO_GID")
if uid: os.chown(path, uid, gid)
```

Comment: Should probably be `os.chown(path, int(uid), int(gid))`